# jsonnet expression to string before evaluation

Tags: jsonnet

Given the following jsonnetfile:

```
{
  expression: self.result,
  result: 3 > 1,
}
```

That evaluates to this:

```
{
   "expression": true,
   "result": true
}
```

Is there a way to convert the expression to string before evaluation? The desired result would be the following:

```
{
   "expression": "3 > 1",
   "result": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `jsonnet` doesn't support `eval()`- alike expressions, the *only* way really is to load such file as text with `importstr()` (then conveniently parse it as YAML¹), also with `import()` to get it parsed as `jsonnet`, then "merge" both objects to *cherry-pick* fields from each one.

Below is a possible approach for the above, of course, it could be generalized for more "complex" root object structure, but it's enough to show the approach.

Note that your original `jsonnetfile` is saved as `foo.yaml`, but with `expression` and `result` fields swapped (as I *think* this is your intent)

### input (foo.yaml)

```yaml
{
  expression: 3 > 1,  
  result: self.expression,
}
```

### code

```jsonnet
local asYAML = std.parseYaml(importstr 'foo.yaml');
local asJsonnet = import 'foo.yaml';

{
  expression: asYAML.expression,
  result: asJsonnet.result,
}
```

### output

```json
{
   "expression": "3 > 1",
   "result": true
}
```

¹ Note that loading jsonnet as YAML will only support a subset of jsonnet, as YAML parser may interfere with other language expressions

Comment: Awesome, and yes you guessed the intent correctly. It was just flipped in the example.

Now to the harder part. Getting the non-technical people to write the expressions in a limited YAML-file and importing it :) Thanks again!